# How to print silently on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, printing

Im working on Android app where I need to print a pdf file siltently.

App starts with intent from my website, downloads the pdf file, and I want it to print the pdf without app or the print preview ever showing up and going straight to printing.

My PrintingManager looks like this:

```
public void print(){

    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
    String jobName = this.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";


    PrintDocumentAdapter pda = new PrintDocumentAdapter(){

        @Override
        public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback){

            //code preparing pdf file for printing
        }

        @Override
        public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras){

            if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                callback.onLayoutCancelled();
                return;
            }


            PrintDocumentInfo pdi = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("Name of file").setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT).build();

            callback.onLayoutFinished(pdi, true);
        }

    };


    printManager.print(jobName, pda, null);
}
```

Do I even need the PrintManager? Is there some way to do it?

Comment: The user needs to be able to configure the print job, such as choosing what printer to print on. Hence, a print dialog will show up when using the Android printing framework.

Comment: Thank you, thats all I wanted to know.

Comment: Dear John, I am also looking for the same solution, have you figured out? if yes could please brief me the steps?