# Is there a way to insert a print job without using PrintManager.print?

Tags: android, printing

I'm working on a very particular application where an Android device is connected to other devices.
These devices will be able to dialog with the Android application via TCP and possibly to ask for printing data.

So as in this situation we don't want to use the standard Android printing mechanism, I was wondering if it would be possible to directly insert my document in the Android spooler without calling `PrintManager.print()`?

Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443774/how-to-print-silently-on-android):

> The user needs to be able to configure the print job, such as choosing what printer to print on. Hence, a print dialog will show up when using the Android printing framework.